# Distributive property of matrix multiplication help

Tags: matrix-equations, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

$$a = {-\frac12(x-μ_1)^{T}Σ^{-1}(x-μ_1)}{ + (\frac12(x-μ_2)^{T}Σ^{-1}(x-μ_2))}$$

$$solution = (μ_2-μ_1)^TΣ^{−1}x-\frac12(μ_2^{T}Σ^{−1}μ_2-μ_1^{T}Σ^{−1}μ_1)$$
Simplify the following equation so that it matches the solution.
I've attempted to simplify the problem using the distributive property of matrix multiplication for $(x − μ)^T(x − μ)$ but I can't reach the correct solution.

Can I please get a step by step approach to help me solve this problem?

\Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/42969)  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note that $x^TAy=y^TA^Tx$ so if $\Sigma$ is symmetric (which I suspect?) then it might help...

Comment: thank you this hint led me to the correct solution.